# File upload for Zip and rar extension not working in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am creating file upload functionality for my blog using codeigniter. in that i am accepting two formats zip|rar.

It gives error as **The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.**. Its working fine if 
change it to other format like image or txt .

Please find the code snippet

```
$config['upload_path'] = './public/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'zip';
        $config['max_size'] = '6000';       
        //$config['file_name'] = $authorName.$config['file_ext'];
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);



        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()){         
            $data['serverMessage'] = "E75";
            $data['uploadError'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $data['message'] =$this->upload->display_errors();

        }else{
            $data['message'] ="Thanks you";
        }

        $this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
        $this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

        $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
        $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");




        $this->load->view('guestpost', $data);
```

Comment: please check the mimetype of zip or rar file you are uploading if it is not exist in config/mimes.php then add it in zip mime array

Comment: already added .. 'zip' =>   array('application/zip', 'application/x-zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/x-compress', 'application/x-compressed', 'multipart/x-zip'),

Comment: check your current file's mime type

Comment: can you please try this 
`$config['allowed_types'] = 'application|zip';
$config['max_size'] = '';` // just in case

Comment: i know it is kinda late, but have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Add 'application/octet-stream' at the end of zip at config/mimes.php ...

```
'zip'   =>  array('application/x-zip', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'application/s-compressed', 'multipart/x-zip', 'application/octet-stream')
```

Answer (score 0):

this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300354/uploading-zip-and-rar-file-not-working-in-codeigniter) may help you

try to change the MIME.php configuration

Answer (score 0):

$config['allowed_types'] = 'application/zip';

try this..