# Uploading zip and rar file not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

setting i have created for allowed type:

```
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'doc|docx|pdf|xls|xlsx|rtf|txt|rar|zip';
```

and in my mine.php

```
  'zip' =>  array('application/x-zip', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed','application/force-download'),
  'rar' =>  array('application/x-rar', 'application/rar','application/x-rar-compressed','application/force-download'),
```

this is all i have configured but when i do the zip or rar upload its shows me error that "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed."

PLEASE HELP ANY ONE .. THANKS IN ADVANCE..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have replaced the `mime.php` configuration for zip and rar to:

```
 'zip'  =>  array('application/x-zip', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed','application/force-download','application/octet-stream'),
 'rar'  =>  array('application/x-rar', 'application/rar','application/x-rar-compressed','application/force-download','application/octet-stream'),
```

I have just added the `application/octet-stream` at the end.. for both the type  and now i am able to upload both zip and rar... :) now i am happy

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best way to check MIME type.

open system/libraries/upload.php in codeigniter framework. Check the commented below. You will get the exact MIME type and include the same MIME type in your mimes.php file.

```
// Set the uploaded data as class variables
        $this->file_temp = $_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'];
        $this->file_size = $_FILES[$field]['size'];
        $this->_file_mime_type($_FILES[$field]);
        $this->file_type = preg_replace("/^(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $this->file_type);
        $this->file_type = strtolower(trim(stripslashes($this->file_type), '"'));
        $this->file_name = $this->_prep_filename($_FILES[$field]['name']);
        $this->file_ext = $this->get_extension($this->file_name);
        $this->client_name = $this->file_name;
        //var_dump($this->file_type); Added by pratikn to check mime type
        //exit();
        // Is the file type allowed to be uploaded?
        if (!$this->is_allowed_filetype()) {
            $this->set_error('upload_invalid_filetype');
            return FALSE;
        }
```