# Why can't I upload zip type file?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I successfully create multiple file upload. But, for some reason it fails to upload zip type files.

```
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH."assets/uploads/";
$path = $config['upload_path'];

$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|xls|xlsx|txt|pdf|sql|html|rar|zip|7z';
$config['max_size'] = '5120';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

If I add this `$this->upload->set_allowed_types('*');`. The zip files are uploaded. But, I don't want to use this. Because it allows all type to be uploaded.

Comment: anything from http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php ?

Comment: no.  when I upload 3 file, (rar, zip and 7z). only rar and 7z are uploaded. Are there limitation in the number of extension that is allowed?

Comment: That I couldn't say and is most bizarre. I've never worked deep enough with CI to say, sorry.

Comment: Ok. thx for responding my question.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you get your solution from someone who may know and was faced with a similar problem, *cheers*

Comment: You should find out what type is internally determined for that file.

Comment: @arkascha what do you mean?

Comment: Well, the framework has to compare the file type it determines for an uploaded file with the list of allowed types. I suspect that your file is internally taken for something else, not for a zip type, why ever. The fist step to troubleshooting is to find out the actual situation. Here that means to find out what is going on internally.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20300469/2275490

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading zip and rar file not working in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300354/uploading-zip-and-rar-file-not-working-in-codeigniter)